# Кэширование последних n строк

Tags: php, html, кэширование

Здравствуйте. У меня на сайте есть скрипт, который парсит кое-что. Собственно, выдает этот скрипт что-то типа этого:

```
http://link.com/123 <br />
http://link.com/321 <br />
http://link.com/456 <br />
http://link.com/654 <br />
```

И в мета-данных страницы указано обновление каждых 60 секунд, но каждый раз появляются новые ссылки, а старые просто исчезают (так было задумано). Теперь нужно сделать так, что бы последние n наборов ссылок (как вверху) сохранялись и выводились.. ну или кэшировались в браузере. Я бы дал код, но он еще дописывается =)

Comment: 1. С чем именно возникла сложность?
2. В каком виде функция возвращает ссылки: в виде массива или строки, выдает сразу всю "порцию" или выводит по одной ссылке с какой-то периодичностью
3. Часть необходимых ссылок должна кешироваться на постоянной основе или достаточно на период сессии.
4. Рассматриваете кеширование на сервере или на клиенте тоже.

Comment: @Deonis 1. Собственно, я понятия не имею, как это реализовать. Ну вообще. Абсолютно. <br />
2. Всю "порцию" сразу, в шаблоне стоит <?php echo $links; ?>. Но сохранять тоже надо "все сразу", так что думаю это не плохо. Скрипт one-page, большего и не нужно. <br />
3. На постоянной. То есть после случайного закрытия скрипта и его остановки все равно должно быть эдакое кэширование<br />
4. Куда угодно, правда как я понимаю, если это на клиенте, то это на период сессии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, из всего вами изложенного, могу предложить [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/17t1vqyz/). Теперь поясню, т.к. большая часть из примера, вам будет не нужна. Две основные функции: getData() и setData() - получают или записывают данные в хранилище (Local Storage). Если ссылки на странице у вас обновляются динамически (*напр. Ajax*), то вызывать функцию setData(), нужно после каждого такого обновления, передавая ей параметром очередную порцию ссылок. Если же ссылки выводятся один раз при загрузке документа, то и вызывать эту функцию тоже достаточно один раз (*ваш К.О.*). Опять же, если ссылки выводятся динамически, то принцип такой же, как в примере: переменной присвоилось значение со ссылками > вывели н экран > записали в LS. Если не динамически, то ссылки нужно подхватывать из DOM.

```
$('output').html(); // для jQuery
document.querySelector('output').innerHTML; // нативный JS
```

В примере я поставил ограничение, на хранение таких "порций" ссылок равное 5. Вы можете поставить свой лимит. LS поддерживает около 5Мб данных, а значит что кроме тысячи порций, еще хватит места для бабушки с дедушкой ;) Хранение в Local Storage постоянное, но, как вы понимаете, только для браузера на котором работаете. Если нужно сделать общедоступное хранилище, то можно записывать в файл, но тогда клиентская часть как бы и не нужна. Потестируйте пример, закрывайте открывайте окно браузера, для получения кеша - жмёте Restore. Потом с вопросами сюда ;)

**UPD** Вариант на сервере

```
// $url - все url-адреса на входе
$arr = preg_split('~<br\s*/?>\n*~', $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$last_ten = implode('<br />', array_slice($arr, -10, 10));
// записываем в файл последние 10 адресов
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $last_ten);
// читаем из файла
echo file_get_contents('filename.txt');
```

**UPD 2**

```
// Запись в кеш
$cache = (array)json_decode( file_get_contents('filename.txt'), 1 );
if( count($cache) >= 10 ) {
    $cache = array_slice($cache, -10, 10);
}
array_push($cache, $links); // $links - ваши ссылки
file_put_contents('filename.txt', json_encode($cache));

// Чтение
$cache = json_decode( file_get_contents('filename.txt'), 1 );
foreach($cache as $part){
    echo $part;
}
```

Comment: Похоже Вы/я не правильно вас понял. Во-первых, мне нужно хранить данные на стороне сервера (желательно).. во вторых я абсолютный ноль в любом JS. Я программист на Java, просто попросили сделать такой-вот скрипт. Лично я, в том коде, который Вы написали, не вижу никакой логики, и понять что Вы там понаписывали я не могу ;) Но в любом случае я попробую каким-либо образом прилепить это на страницу, а потом напишу вам =) Спасибо.
PS: страница обновляется html'ом и так выводятся новые ссылки, по этому, как я понял, это не подойдет.

Comment: @AlexWells, на сервере - так на сервере, просто вы написали, что сохранять "Куда угодно". Из функции получаете список ссылок, если хранить в файле, то пишите: file_put_contents('filename.txt', $urls, FILE_APPEND); В случае использования флага FILE_APPEND, данные не будут перезаписываться, а будут добавляться в конец файла. Чтение из файла: file_get_contents('filename.txt'); Понятное дело, что есть вариант хранить в базе, но тут вопрос в целесообразности и решать вам.

Comment: это уже получается какой-то список.. а мне нужно последних 10 пар, я писал другому пользователю вверху..

Comment: @AlexWells, ох, вы привередливый :)) Смотрите обновление в моём ответе

Comment: ох Вы, не внимательный =)) "а мне нужно последних 10 пар".. пар, а не ссылок) )) ))))) Но я все равно помечу ответ как правильный, а то я Вам тут мозги ем, а вы все равно помогаете =)

Comment: @AlexWells, Ну, почему же... Давайте уже добъём.  Я боюсь предполагать, но что значит "последние 10 пар". Пар чего? Пар ссылок? Так это будет 20 в сумме. Или же это пар "порций ссылок", а в каждой "порции" по 10 ссылок?

Comment: каждый раз при загрузке страницы либо выводится сообщение 'Nothing new' либо куча ссылок, что я и называю "парой". Если выведено 'Nothing new' то кэшировать этого не надо. Если ссылки, то нужно закэшировать всю "пару" ссылок, хоть их будет 100, хоть 1. И вот таких "пар" нужно 10, а не 10 ссылок. 
То есть в сумме на странице может быть одна ссылка, может не быть вообще, а могут быть все 100 =)

Comment: @AlexWells, обновил. Единственное, что вам надо делать - это проверять: есть ссылки или нет. Если же это строка в переменной, то хоть через тот же if($links != 'Nothing new') то записываем

Comment: спасибо вам большое. Коммент пометил как правильный и репутацию ответа вверх. Вопрос: как выводить полученый массив наоборот? Так получается, что новые ссылки идут последними, а нужно наоборот.. И еще раз большое-большое спасибо, безумно рад!

Comment: @AlexWells, перевернуть массив - функция array_reverse(). То есть, изменить строку таким образом:

$cache = array_reverse( json_decode( file_get_contents('filename.txt'), 1 ) );

Comment: я просто поменял foreach на for и сделал итерацию наоборот, и все, как не странно, работает! Почему так - потому что array_reverse + мой цикл = 2 цикла, а так 1 =) 
Спасибо! Чем еще я могу помочь Вам? Ибо на стаке я не давно, понятия не имею, есть ли тут какая-то репутация или что-то типа того..

Comment: В следующий раз, формулируйте вопрос более конкретно - это и будет помощь ;) Успехов.